# Bethe-Bloch equation (for Stopping Power Calculations); Quantum Mechanical Derivation

Tags: nuclear-physics

[Bethe-Bloch equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethe_formula) using quantum mechanical calculations is

$$-\dfrac{\mathrm dE}{\mathrm dx} = 2 \pi N_{a} r_{e}^{2} m_{e} c^{2} \rho \dfrac{Z}{A}  \dfrac{z^{2}}{\beta^{2}}\left[\ln\left(\dfrac{2m_{e} \gamma ^{2} v^{2} W_{max}}{I^{2}}\right) - 2\beta^{2} - \delta 2\frac{C}{Z}\right]$$

Is it possible to derive this partially using basic quantum mechanics?
At least the derivation of I the Mean Excitation Potential, $W_{max}$. the maximum energy transfer(i.e head on collision).

$$W_{max} = \dfrac{2m_{e} c^{2} \eta^{2}}{1+2s \sqrt{1+\eta^{2}} + s^{2}};\qquad s=m_{e}/M;\eta=\beta\gamma.$$

Comment: Has your question been answered I've been wondering how to derive this for a while I'm working through a paper that brings up Bethe-Bloch but I've been clueless how to derive it.